# How do they load a url inside a webview instead of androids internal browser?

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to achieve this: [MKyong - WebView](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/).
To get a hint at what exactly, then take a look at the last picture before "Download Source Code".

My applications code is:

```
bookingView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);
bookingView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
bookingView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

But what that code does is opening the url(in this case Google) inside the default browser/internal browser in android and it's not meant to be that in the android application I am making.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add this line before the `loadUrl()` call

```
bookingView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Answer (score 8):

**This is the answer:**

**Features**

1. Load a URL on WebView
2. Open another page in the website on Webview dont on local Browser.
3. If you press on backbutton will go to the before page dont out of app.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        WebView webview;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
            webView();
        }

    //Metodo llamar el webview
    private void webView(){
        //Habilitar JavaScript (Videos youtube)
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        //Handling Page Navigation
        webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        //Load a URL on WebView
        webview.loadUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/");
    }

    // Metodo Navigating web page history
    @Override public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webview.canGoBack()) {
            webview.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    // Subclase WebViewClient() para Handling Page Navigation
    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("stackoverflow.com")) { //Force to open the url in WEBVIEW
                return false;
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Include this in AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.webview" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**RESULT**

**START PAGE**

[image: Start page]

**ANOTHER PAGE IN THE WEBSITE ON WEBVIEW**

[image: Click in another page in the start page]